# Rails - initialize object instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization

I have two arrays which I would like to initialise to `[]` in my `Prediction` model's object.

If I try:

```
def initialize
    @first_estimation = []
    @last_estimation = []
end
```

Then many of my unit tests fail.

```
 Failure/Error: assign(:prediction, Prediction.new(
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

However, if I try:

```
def after_initialize
    @first_estimation = []
    @last_estimation = []
end
```

Then the arrays do not get instantiated.

How can I instantiate the arrays when the object is constructed without altering anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I see a parenthesis here `Prediction.new(` I deduce you try to pass params.

But your `initialize` doesnt accept any => boom

---

But wait, is it an ActiveRecord model?

If so, you have to use:

```
 after_initialize :set_arrays

 def set_arrays
   @first_estimation = []
   @last_estimation = []
 end
```

and maybe use `attr_accessor` too, but dont know what you expect